# How do I split my app into modules?

Tags: react-native

This seems trivial, but I can't find any documentation for it.

I want to split my (very basic) app up into UI and non-UI modules. So I've created this:

```
/* datahandler.js */

export class DataHandler {                                                                           

  getSuppliers(search,limit,offset) {                                                                
    let params = { method: 'GET',                                                                    
                   headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },                                        
                   body: null };                                                                     

    let url = 'http://url.for.data.service.goes.here';                                   

    return fetch( `${url}?params=${search},${limit},${offset}`, params )                             
      .then((response) => response.json() )                                                          
      .catch((error)   => { console.error("fetch caught:" + error); } );                             

  }                                                                                                  

}
```

But I don't know where to put the module in order for it to be recognised.  If I put it in the top level and call it with `import {DataHandler} from 'datahandler';`, then I get:

```
error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `datahandler` from `/home/andy/andy/try_react/try1/index.android.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /home/andy/andy/try_react/try1/node_modules

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --reset-cache`.
    at UnableToResolveError (/home/andy/andy/try_react/try1/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:488:5)
    at p.catch.error (/home/andy/andy/try_react/try1/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:366:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
Bundling `index.android.js`  0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

It seems like I could drop the file into the node_modules directory, but I don't want to do that.  Is there some sort of module path, or a manifest of files to include, that I'm not seeing in the documentation?

---

Incidentally I did try `react-native new-library --name="datahandler"`, but all it did was to create a Libraries directory, and not the promised templates (for a whole library?  I'm pretty certain I don't want that, anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just

```
import (DataHandler} from './datandler';
```

I was missing the `./`.

But: I still can't find anywhere this is documented.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would simply use the path of your file to grab your own classes.

```
rootDir
.. pages
... page.jsx
.. modules
... datahandler.js
```

Your module would look like that

```
export default class DataHandler {
...
}
```

and in your page

```
import DataHandler from '../modules/datahandler'
```